# How to further filter the result from searching step?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a table student_tb that stores student_name and class_name

```
student_id | student_name | class_name
   1       |       John   |     1
   2       |       Herry  |     2
   3       |       Peter  |     1
   4       |       Tom    |     2
```

I created a form to search student name in the database as follows:

```
<form style="text-align: center;" method='POST'>
    <input type="text"   name='input_text' id='input_text' placeholder="Input text to search" required>   
     <button type="submit" name='search' value="search" ">Search</button>
</form> 

<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM student_tb WHERE student_name LIKE '%".$_POST['input_text']."%' "; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
        <ul>
          <li><h3><?php echo $row["student_name"] . $row["class_name"]; ?></h3></li>            
        </ul>
     <?php }}?>
</div>
```

Assume that, I will add two check boxes which are used to further filter the result from searching step. Could you guide me how to implement it when I click the check box? For example, I type 'T', the searching result is `Peter 1` and `Tom 2`. After that, I click the check box `class 1`, the result only remains Peter 1. Thank you so much

```
<div id="filter" style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" id="class1" name="class1" value="class1">
    <label for="class1">Class 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="class2" name="class2">
    <label for="class2">Class2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define these checkboxes as array `(name="class[]")` , give them a values equal to your class_name IDs and check them while building your SQL query:

```
<form style="text-align: center;" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name='input_text' id='input_text' placeholder="Input text to search" required>
    <div id="filter" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="class1" name="class[]" value="1">
        <label for="class1">Class 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="class2" name="class[]" value="2">
        <label for="class2">Class2</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="search" value="search">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            dump($_POST);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_tb WHERE student_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['input_text'] . "%' ";
            if(isset($_POST['class'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['class'] AS $k => $v) {
                    if ($k == 0) {
                        $sql .= " AND (class_name = " . $v;
                    } else {
                        $sql .= " OR class_name = " . $v;
                    }
                }
                $sql .= ")";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><h3><?php echo $row["student_name"] . $row["class_name"]; ?></h3></li>
                </ul>
            <?php }
        } ?>
</div>
```

Built SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    student_tb
WHERE
    student_name LIKE '%T%'
    AND (class_name = 1 OR class_name = 2)
```

Note that if you send more than one checkbox, you must combine them with OR clause in order to filter data properly.

**UPDATE**: Here is the script (HTML & PHP) with ability to:

- search by string;
- to apply checkbox filter with automatic submit;
- to keep all values after submit;
- to reset form;

---

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formSubmit" value="1">
    <input
        type="text"
        name='input_text'
        id='input_text'
        placeholder="Input text to search"
        required
        value="<?php if (isset($_POST['input_text'])) echo $_POST['input_text'] ?>">
    <div id="filter">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="class1"
            name="class[0]"
            value="1"
            onclick="this.form.submit()" <?php if (isset($_POST['class'][0])) echo $_POST['class'][0] ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
        <label for="class1">Class 1</label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="class2"
            name="class[1]"
            value="2"
            onclick="this.form.submit()" <?php if (isset($_POST['class'][1])) echo $_POST['class'][1] ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
        <label for="class2">Class2</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="search" value="search">Search</button>
    <button type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'">Reset</button>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
            dump($_POST);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_tb WHERE student_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['input_text'] . "%' ";
            if (isset($_POST['class'])) {
                $c = 0;
                $sql .= " AND (";
                    foreach ($_POST['class'] AS $k => $v) {
                        if($c == 0) $sql .= "class_name = " . $v;
                        else        $sql .= " OR class_name = " . $v;
                        $c++;
                    }
                $sql .= ")";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><h3><?php echo $row["student_name"] . $row["class_name"]; ?></h3></li>
                </ul>
            <?php }
        } ?>
</div>
```

The change is a bit static and can be improved for sure, but you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. It worked well if I check a box and search. However, if I did not check any box and insert text to search. It has a minor error as follows:  (Notice: Undefined index: class in index.php on line 26
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 26
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in index.php on line 35)....In that case, the search process just do WHERE student_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['input_text'] . "%' "

Comment: Yes, my miss, we need to check is any checkbox is passed as POST parameter - check updated script.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. It is really short code and easy to understand. I just want to ask you one more question. Is it possible to make a live showing? For example,  the filtering result will show when I click the checkbox 1

Comment: Instead of clicking on button Search?

Comment: No. First, I did not click any checkbox. After click button search, I have two students. Then, I click one of checkbox, it will filter the searching result after I click it

Comment: Yes, is possible, but you need to modify the script a bit in order to achieve that, like to keep input field value into it after first submit, to add `onclick="this.form.submit()"` onto checkboxes (and again to keep its states) and to look for some other POST value, but not for `search` in order to detect is the form has been submitted.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it but it was not  successful. Let I make it clearly. I type 'T'  and click the search button (uncheck in checkbox 1 and 2). The result is Tom 2 and Peter 1. Then, I choose checkbox 1 (denotes for class 1), it will automatically show the result is Peter 1. Could you help me to update it in your answer? online demo as http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/ajax-filter/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Just delete  dump($_POST); and it work well

Comment: I checked your code. It worked well. But it has one issue. Assume that I want to locate text and button on the top page, and checkboxes in left page. It means I must put them in individual div. However, your code looks fix them. Do we have any way to fix it for flexible design ?

Comment: At least they are under same `<form>`, the place does not matter. I've put them like that in order the code to be readable. In practice you can place it whenever you want. Simpy open the form right after `body` tag and close it again before closing the body. Then you are be able to design you page as you want.

Comment: @ mitkosoft: I created an online share about my issue. I want to locate the button search and text as in header div (as a red button). Currently,we have two search buttons and two texts. They are same, I just make two buttons for showing current location and expected location. I just want to move the below search button and text to the new location as my expected (red button and text behind the red button) http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=9NnEiv7m4R